# Has anyone figured out a way to confirm whether the Android in-app-review dialog was shown?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cordova, task

I understand that there is no official way to determine whether the review card was shown to the user or not. But I am curious whether anyone has found a way around this, perhaps by inspecting the UI?

Note: I am not interested in knowing whether the user actually reviewed or not. All I need to know is whether the dialog was shown!

I'm currently using the cordova plugin - `cordova-launch-review` to request an in-app-review dialog. It accepts a callback which is called after a successful *request*, but as far as I can tell, it has no way of knowing whether the dialog was actually shown or not.

Link to the plugin repo: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-launch-review/blob/master/src/android/LaunchReview.java

I'll paste the code the plugin runs when requesting the review dialog below. It's pretty standard stuff, very similar to Android's official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(cordova.getContext());
        Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
        request.addOnCompleteListener(requestTask -> {
            try{
                if (taskWasSuccessful(requestTask)) {
                    ReviewInfo reviewInfo = requestTask.getResult();
                    Task<Void> flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(cordova.getActivity(), reviewInfo);
                    flow.addOnCompleteListener(launchTask -> {
                        try{
                            if (taskWasSuccessful(launchTask)) {
                                callbackContext.success("requested");
                            }else{
                                handleTaskFailed(launchTask, callbackContext);
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            handleException(e, callbackContext);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        handleException(e, callbackContext);
                    });
                } else {
                    handleTaskFailed(requestTask, callbackContext);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                handleException(e, callbackContext);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            handleException(e, callbackContext);
        });
```